# What triggers Photo Library authorization request? iOS

Tags: ios, ios9, photosframework, phphotolibrary

Is there a way to find what triggers Photo Library authorization request?

I can't find what line exactly triggers the permission request for Photo Library.

I've searched workspace for `[PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization]` - no luck.

What should I search for to find line that triggers Photo Library authorization request?

Device is on iOS 9.

Comment: well, voting down and not posting an answer isn't very polite, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, it was `[[PHCachingImageManager alloc] init]`.
This line calls for permission.

Comment: It appears that `PHPhotoLibrary.shared().register()` also triggers permission request

Answer (score -1):

If you read [the documentation for `requestAuthorization:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHPhotoLibrary_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/PHPhotoLibrary/requestAuthorization:), you'll see:

> The first time your app uses `PHAsset`, `PHCollection`, `PHAssetCollection`, or `PHCollectionList` methods to fetch content from the library, or uses one of the methods listed in [Applying Changes to the Photo Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHPhotoLibrary_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014404-CH1-SW2) to request changes to library content, Photos automatically and asynchronously prompts the user to request authorization. Alternatively, you can call this method to prompt the user at a time of your choosing.

Comment: Well, thanks, I did read it before posting the question. My guess was that it was something outside Photos framework, because, as I said, I do not import it by that time. Is that possible?

Comment: Are you sure it's a photos authorisation request and not the recording permission request?

Comment: The documentation is misleading. Just initializing a `PHCachingImageManager` already triggers the authorization request, but the paragraph you quote sounds like it wouldn't, as we don't call any of the mentioned methods. I had the same problem as OP.